# Building VST3 example does not build vst3 file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, vst

I am trying to building an out of the box example project for the steinberg Vst3 sdk.

I am trying to build the adelay example.

When I build it, it outputs ADelay.bsc, ADelay.exp, ADelay.lib, and adelay.pdb. But it does not output either a dll or a vst3, which would be expected for this kind of plugin. I read in another thread that you should change the Target in project properties to .dll, but that did not work for me at all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using VS?

If so, right click on ADelay->Properties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories->Edit, then you set your path to ...\VST3 SDK\public.sdk\source;

Then go back to Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Output File->inherit from parent or project defaults.

Then run it. You should find a .vst3 file inside your debug folder.